# How to sort from an array list and print the maximum two values

Tags: java

I have an array list called team. Team has size 4 and stores the attributes called team points.

I want to print the top two vales of team points from this array list.
Can someone show me the code to do so? 
Answers welcome!

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Comparator` in java:

Suppose your `Team` class look like:

```
public class Team {
   private int point;
   // Getter, setter
}
```

And you have list of `Team`: List teams

Then you can do it by:

```
Collections.sort(teams, Comparator.comparing(Team::getPoint).reversed());
```

This mean: Sort the `teams` arraylist, based on `team.getPoint()` but in reversed order (maximum list first)

Then `teams.get(0), teams.get(1)` are your two 1st and 2nd team.

Answer (score -2):

you can easily use sort function for sorting the array

```
sort($team);
$arrlength = count($team);
for($x = $arrlength; $x =$arrlength - 2; $x--) {
    echo $team[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Arrays.sort(team, 1, 5);

Comment: This is not Java.